# how to run script automatically when certain applications are opened

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

i want to run a bash script whenever i open vlc
i tried to put the alias of vlc to my script and open vlc but this only works when opened from terminal i want my script to run even when vlc is opened using GUI

Comment: What desktop you're using?

Comment: Open VLC from within a script?  Just run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the `desktop entry` to point to a wrap script that call `vlc` and then your own script:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/vlc_wrap.sh
#!/bin/bash
# swap the order if matters
./path/to/your/script.sh &>/dev/null &
/usr/bin/vlc &>/dev/null &
```

Then edit the `desktop entry` for the vlc : `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` and modify the line which hold the `Exec`  keyword.
The new one should point to the wrapper you have just write, and so become:

`Exec=/usr/local/bin/vlc_wrap.sh`

I have shown the way to do that in `gnome` look up the documentation for the desktop you use.

Answer (score 1):

- auditd
- run a script which does something like this

```
#! /bin/bash
while :; do
  test -n "`pgrep vlc`" && do_something
  sleep 1
done
```

- lastly

```
mv /usr/bin/vlc /usr/bin/vlc.bin
cat /usr/bin/vlc
#! /bin/bash
nohup /usr/bin/vlc.bin "$@" &> /dev/null < /dev/null &
do_something
```